# Adding Dynamically a row to repeater at particular position

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net

wants to add a TextBox in repeater on Check Box event. on Checked calls JQuery Function and if checked then Values Becomes true and Checks for hdnQuesId,if hdnQuesID==1 and CheckBox Checked it adds A textbox after that checkbox dynamically.

HTML:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptMedical" OnItemDataBound="rptMedical_ItemDataBound" >
           <HeaderTemplate>
            <ul class="full question-list">
                </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <li class="full">
                    <p class="question full">
                        Q.<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblQuestion" Text='<%# Eval("Question")%>'></asp:Label></p>
                 <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdnQuestionCode" Value='<%# Eval("QuestionCode")%>' />
                 <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdnQuestionId" Value='<%# Eval("Id")%>' />

                    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptMember">
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                             <ul class="full ans-list member-3">
                        </HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                      <li class="fl grid js-question-details-holder">
                          <div class="full answer-lable">
                             <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblMemberName" class="fl check-option">
                                    <label class="switch">
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="chkAnsr" runat="server" value="false" class="switch-input js-member-question answerCheck">
                                        <span data-off="No" data-on="Yes" class="switch-label full"></span><span class="switch-handle anim">
                                            <i class="ui-icon-20 ico-switch-handle"></i></span>
                                    </label>
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
                              </div>


                    </div>
                          </li>

                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            </ul>
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>
                    </li>
            </ItemTemplate>   
             <FooterTemplate>
                 </ul>
             </FooterTemplate>

             </asp:Repeater>
```

JQuery:

```
$('.answerCheck').click(function () {
    var objId = this.id;
    var check = objId.split('_');
    var hdnQuesId =$('#'+ prefix +'rptMedical_hdnQuestionId_'+check[3]).val();
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('#' + objId).val("true");
        var ans = $('#' + objId).val();
        if (ans == true && hdnQuesId != 1)
            {
            $('.noki').addClass('hide');
            }
        else
            {

            var box = document.createElement("input");
            box.setAttribute("type", "text");
            box.setAttribute("value", "text");
            box.setAttribute("runat", "server");
            var x = document.getElementById((this).id);
            x.appendChild(box);
            $('.noki').removeClass('hide');
        }
        }
}
```

this didn't add textbox in repater on Check Box Event of Particular row in Repeater

Comment: You might want to add the part of the DOM you're working on. Without the HTML, it is quite difficult to see and analyzse what's going on here.